# What is the best way to print regex hits?

Tags: regex, unix, sed, awk

I would like to know the best, most easy way to print only the `regex` hits.

Lats say you have this regex `ab[a-z][0-9]+xyz`

And the following data:

```
cat file
her are my databc653xyzc test
some data abc12345xyzmore
what abx764xyzyes thisa sdabu9483xyzfk
not this data
```

Then I like to get this result:

```
abc653xyz
abc12345xyz
abx764xyz abu9483xyz
```

This is what I have found that seems to work:

`awk` version:

```
awk -F¤ '$0~reg {gsub(reg,"¤&¤");for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) printf "%s ",$i;print ""}' reg="ab[a-z][0-9]+xyz" file
abc653xyz
abc12345xyz
abx764xyz abu9483xyz
```

It will fail if data does contains `¤` or any character used as field separator.

A `gnu awk` (prints the second hit, but on separate line)

```
awk -v RS="ab[a-z][0-9]+xyz" 'RT{print RT}' file
abc653xyz
abc12345xyz
abx764xyz
abu9483xyz
```

`sed` version (missed the second hit)

```
sed -n 's/^.*\(ab[a-z][0-9]\+xyz\).*$/\1/p' file
abc653xyz
abc12345xyz
abx764xyz
```

Comment: you gave 3 examples but you didn't give what output do you want to get if there are more than one hit in one line. each hit in a new line? or group the hits in same line if they are from same line?

Comment: @kent updated my question to take in count more than one hit on the line.

Comment: Updated with a working `awk` that can have multiple hit on one line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `grep`:

```
grep -oP 'ab[a-z][0-9]+xyz' filename
```

It'd also work for any number of hits on one line.

```
$ cat file
her are my databc653xyzc test xyabc42xyzghi
some data abc12345xyzmore
what abx764xyzyes
not this data
$ grep -oP 'ab[a-z][0-9]+xyz' file
abc653xyz
abc42xyz
abc12345xyz
abx764xyz
```

---

If you need multiple hits present on one line in the input to be present on the same line in the output, you could use perl:

```
perl -lne '@m = $_ =~ /(ab[a-z][0-9]+xyz)/g; print join(" ",@m) if @m' inputfile
```

This produces:

```
abc653xyz abc42xyz
abc12345xyz
abx764xyz
```

for the sample input in the above example.

Comment: I like this. It also print hits if there are more hits in one line.  Would it be possible to get hits printed on same line if thy are found on same line?

Comment: with a special attention to `egrep` if available

Comment: @Jotne grep print each line once where regex is found at least 1 time so 1, 2 or more hit only print 1 line in final result

Comment: @Jotne Updating with a perl alternative that would produce multiple hits in a line on the same line in the output.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether its the best or not, you can also use Perl Oneliner for this as you are from unix.

```
cat input.txt | perl -ne '$\ = $/; print for /(ab[a-z][0-9]+xyz)/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

it is hard to group matches in line with grep.

if **gawk** is ok for you, I think `split()` could help. Read man page for detail usage, example:

```
kent$  cat f
abc653xyz bar abc12345xyz foo abx764xyz

kent$  awk '{c=split($0,a,"ab[a-z][0-9]+xyz",s)}c>1{for(x=1;x<=c-1;x++)printf "%s%s", s[x],(x==c-1? RS:FS)}' f
abc653xyz abc12345xyz abx764xyz
```

Comment: `gawk` is fine. This gives correct output, thanks :)